# Model with constructor vs. Model without constructor ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a project in `ASP.NET MVC`. I've been looking for some learning resources regarding the subject and I've come across a scenario which I'm searching for clarification. Suppose:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FooName { get; set; }
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Bar
{
    public Bar()
    {
        this.Foos = new List<Foo>;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BarDesc { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

I mean, in what way does it differ from that of a model Bar with no constructor? Please disregard any errors in the properties (if there any) or possible relationship within entities, since I just want clarification about having a constructor inside a model. Thanks!

Comment: Model is just a C# class, nothing more. There's nothing specific to models or ASP.NET MVC here.

Comment: Yes I know that one. I just want some clarifications.

Answer (score 11):

With the constructor you've shown, `Bar.Foos` will be an empty List of type Foo.

Without the constructor, `Bar.Foos` will be null (unless you initialize it elsewhere).

It's the same difference you'd see between these two lines:

```
List<SomeType> test1 = null;
List<SomeType> test2 = new List<SomeType>();
```

Assuming you're using C# 6, another way of initializing it without a constructor is:

```
public class Bar
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string BarDesc { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Foo> Foos { get; set; } = new List<Foo>();
}
```

Which of the 3 techniques you choose will be up to you, based on whether you always want the property to be initialized or not, if you have multiple constructors, which you think looks better, how you feel about null collection references vs empty collections etc.

Comment: Thanks man. Does it mean that for every class with a List on it, I should initialize the list? @mason

Comment: @ImmanuelValle I added one final sentence to my answer that addresses the decision you must make.

Comment: I would recommend always initializing to an empty list. Then you don't need to worry about checking for null

Comment: @KeithRousseau You may always choose to initialize your lists (that's what I do too) but other developers may not, so you still have to worry about the potential NullReferenceException if you consume other's code.

Comment: Sure, I meant with internal code you don't need to worry about it

Comment: @KeithRousseau Yes, but I just wanted to make that point for Immanuel's benefit. The point being "write your code to minimize mistakes, but don't trust others to do the same".

Comment: Thanks for the both of you. Oh. and nice CV btw, @mason. :D