# Why we need to constructor inside a model in ASP.NET MVC using C#, and what is the purpose of this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, constructor, model

```
public class TagVM
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
}

public class TagListVM
{
    public List<TagVM> TagList { get; set; }

    public TagListVM()
    {
        TagList = new List<TagVM>();
    }
}
```

Why do we use `TagListVM` constructor and what is purpose of it?

Comment: The purpose would be to create an instance (Object) from the class `TagListVM`. Objects of classes are representations of their class. Also, the constructor, in this case, inits the member field `TagList`. Without doing this, the list would be unusable. You should read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html

Answer (score 0):

Without the constructor TagList  will be null (unless you initialize it elsewhere).

for more refer this [Model with constructor vs. Model without constructor ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34425666/model-with-constructor-vs-model-without-constructor-asp-net-mvc)